# Jasper Reports gives design error when setting dynamic left and right margins

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using JasperReports-6.2.2 with java to export pdf file. Jasper tempalte 'template.jrxml' is created using iReports 5.6.0

.jrxml file is loaded using JRXmlLoader

```
JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load("template.jrxml");
design.setTopMargin(20);
design.setBottomMargin(20); 
design.setLeftMargin(50);
JasperReport jasperReport = jasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
```

This gives error : **Report Design not valid.The columns and the margins do not fit the page width.**

How to set dynamic left and right margin??

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that left margin + column width + right margin = page width. 
You have to set all this properties in the JasperDesign. http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JasperDesign.html#setPageWidth(int)

Best regards

Comment: Thank you its working, but data inside bands and table is getting overflowed from right margin so not working as expected.